# User is taken to Canvas Page instead of App Profile Page, after clicking in search results dropdown

Tags: facebook, search, canvas

When a user searches our App in the facebook search box, a drop down of search results is shown. 
If the user now clicks the search icon, he gets "All Results" page and then when he clicks our App he is taken to our "App Profile Page". 
So far so good, but...

If the user clicks on the App from the search results dropdown, the user is taken to the "Canvas Page".

I need the user to always be taken to the "App Page".

Thanks!

Comment: After some searching looks like this is By Design: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/604/

Search typeahead traffic now goes directly to Apps

When users type a Canvas app name in Search, the typeahead link now takes them to the app instead of the App Profile Page. The initial results from an A/B test showed a significant increase in Search typeahead Canvas traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether the following approach works with app pages, but it works with pages. It might work for you. Check if the user is on the Page. If he is not make a redirect:

```
<!--  Check whether on facebook page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function NotInFacebookFrame() {
            return top === self;
    }
    function ReferrerIsFacebookApp() {
            if(document.referrer) {
                return document.referrer.indexOf("apps.facebook.com") != -1;
            }
            return false;
    }
    if (NotInFacebookFrame() || ReferrerIsFacebookApp()) {
            top.location.replace("http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_NAME/PAGE_ID?sk=APP_ID");
    }
</script>
```

By the way: Facebook is removing App Profile Pages on February 1st, 2012. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/